# Limit Select statement to last 10 days

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I'm trying to implement a search-by interface that allows the user to search for things that have been added for the database in the last 10 days only and then have the results displayed in a jtable. I am receiving a syntax error for my sql statement, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it as it seems right to me. I know that the error shows where the syntax is wrong, but I'm not sure what exactly is incorrect or how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
  package project_files;



import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import project_files.registration_test;
import project_files.root_login;
import project_files.gui_interface;
import project_files.video_interface;

import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class searchby {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    searchby window = new searchby();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public searchby() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void video_interface() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 523, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lbSearch = new JLabel("Search by");
        lbSearch.setBounds(209, 12, 100, 15);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbSearch);

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search by");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"video name", "video description", "video_city", "video_subject", "video_tags"}, 0);
                try {

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdatabase", "root", "pass1234");
                            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                            String sql = "SELECT *, (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AS diff" + 
                                    "FROM video " + 
                                    "WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY))";
                            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                            if(rs.next())
                            {
                                 String d = rs.getString("video_name");
                                 String e = rs.getString("video_description");
                                 String f = rs.getString("video_city");
                                 String g = rs.getString("video_subject");
                                 String h = rs.getString("video_tags");
                                 model.addRow(new Object[]{d, e, f, g, h});
                                    table.setModel(model);
                            {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "videos selected Successfully...");
                            }
                            }

                            con.close();
                } catch(Exception e) {System.out.print (e);}






            }});
        btnSearch.setBounds(23, 203, 130, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnSearch);



        JButton btnNewExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnNewExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                JFrame frmLogin_sys = new JFrame("Exit");
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmLogin_sys, "Confirm if you want to exit", "Login System",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)== JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewExit.setBounds(373, 203, 114, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewExit);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setBounds(12, 175, 499, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        separator_1.setBounds(12, 36, 499, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator_1);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(103, 61, 285, 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);




    }
}
```

and my error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'videoWHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)' at line 1
```

Comment: Your error says 'videoWHERE meaning video and where has no space, your code suggest no space in diffFROM. Correct both

Comment: Thank you! Glad it was a simple error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot a space after "AS diff" :)

Comment: i would say we forgot a leading space before `FROM` and before `WHERE`. When generating SQL dynamically, I don't look at "missing space after" as the way to look at it. I look at it is needing to include a space *before* I tack on something else to the existing SQL string, whether it's `JOIN dual` or `AND foo =` or `ORDER BY ...` I think in terms of needing to include a space before (and as part of) what I am adding.

Answer (score 1):

Its so obvious right here: `'videoWHERE`

Always read the beginning of error message, the answer usually there:

> right syntax to use near:

When you concat, dont save up on spaces before and after quotes, use extra/double spaces no problems.